# Tkinter Label text is Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

A hoy hoy, I would like to know how I can take a parameter in a function and make it a label and also then .grid_forget() label again (Answer is on a "Restart?" window). I'm making a currency converter from scratch and my code is terrible.

Comment: Maybe post an example of your code to see what you have at the moment? Saying your code is terrible doesnt help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at one of my Tkinter programs. Look at where it says counter. That is the variable. The Tkinter website is also so helpful! Good luck!

```
from tkinter import *

import sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry("480x320")
root.title("School Days Left!")

global counter
counter = 30

def upClick():
    global counter
    counter += 1

def downClick():
    global counter
    counter -= 1
    mButton1.config(text = counter, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge', pady = "100")

mButton1 = Button(text = counter, command = downClick, height = 4000, width = 320, font = ("Monospace", 200))
mButton1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Whats basically happening is I want to update the "counter" from 30 before label is displayed. how can I do :/

Comment: By creating a function like downClick the when you do Label(text = counter, command =  downClick,.....

Comment: mbutton.config was what I needed Thanks Brendan,